# cakephp 3 on live shared server intl PHP extension

Tags: cakephp-3.0, php-extension, sharedservices

I have cakephp3 application and along with other installation requirements `intl PHP extension` is not supported on shared servers `iPage` and `Hostgator`
is there some alternative or to run cakephp3 on shared server and what is this `intl PHP extension` exactly doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change to a hoster that doesn't want you to share your liver with them, and instead supplies you with the most basic PHP extensions. That way you can happily run CakePHP without being in constant fear of a bleeding diathesis.

That being said, this really isn't the place to explain (again) what the `intl` extension is, this is very well documented, and further info about it can be found all over the internet, so I'd suggest that you do some research on that topic, starting with **http://php.net/intl**.

Running CakePHP without `intl` support is possible, but a rather bad idea, since you're loosing all the internationalisation features that rely on it, like formatting dates and numbers, translating messages, etc. Anyways, if you insinst, check for example **https://github.com/hraq/cake-intl**.